# What is a good way to determine the optimal value of max_workers for multi-processing in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

I have a Python script that will be used for automation. It runs system commands and stores the result in a database. It contains the following line:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 3)
```

I don't know what value to set max_workers as. I've seen people say that the optimal value of max_workers? I've heard people say it depends on the machine but haven't elaborated further. I've also read that the default value in Python 3 is the number of processors * 5. If there is no universally optimal solution, then what's a good way at approaching a locally optimal solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
import os
max_workers = os.cpu_count()
```

Comment: That just tells me the amount of logical processors my computer has, which is 8. Setting it as this value doesn't seem optimal as the default value for max_workers would be 8 * 5, which is a lot more than just 8.

Comment: What I suggested was a `locally optimal` solution in current practice. The real number depends on what task you're trying to do and ofcourse, you can tune it.

Answer (score 0):

Brian Goetz in his famous book "Java Concurrency in Practice" recommends the following formula:

> Number of threads = Number of Available Cores * (1 + Wait time /
> Service time)

**Waiting time** - is the time spent waiting for IO bound tasks to complete, say waiting for HTTP response from remote service.

(not only IO bound tasks, it could be time waiting to get monitor lock or time when thread is in WAITING/TIMED_WAITING state)

**Service time** - is the time spent being busy, say processing the HTTP response, marshaling/unmarshaling, any other transformations etc.

**Wait time / Service time** - this ratio is often called blocking coefficient.

A computation-intensive task has a blocking coefficient close to 0, in this case, the number of threads is equal to the number of available cores. If all tasks are computation intensive, then this is all we need. Having more threads will not help.

*For example:*

A worker thread makes a call to a microservice, serializes response into JSON and executes some set of rules. The microservice response time is 50ms, processing time is 5ms. We deploy our application to a server with a dual-core CPU:

> 2 * (1 + 50 / 5) = 22 // optimal thread pool size

But this example is oversimplified. Besides an HTTP connection pool, your application may have requests from JMS and probably a JDBC connection pool.

If you have different classes of tasks it is best practice to use multiple thread pools, so each can be tuned according to its workload.

Full article you can find [here](https://engineering.zalando.com/posts/2019/04/how-to-set-an-ideal-thread-pool-size.html)